# NSImage initwithData memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsimage

When I wanna create a NSImage object, I encountered memory leak. I compiled the code by:
`clang -o test test.m -framework Foundation -fsanitize=leak -framework CoreGraphics -framework AppKit`, the clang I used is from this way: [gist](https://gist.github.com/datlife/c754535f18b422f6b8d59028c7f31bac)

```
// test.m
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <Foundation/NSURL.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s path/to/image\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
    NSData* content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    while(true) {
        NSImage* img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:content];
        [img release];
    }

    [content release];
    [path release];
    return 0;
}
```

Then I invoked it by `./test test.tiff`, asan reported error that `initWithData` has memory leak.
If it runs in while loop, the memory consumption keeps increasing.

It works with the answer provided by @Asperi. But when I want to do more works related with NSImage, like this: this code will crash, because the `CGImageRelease(cgImg);` and `[img release];` can not be enabled meanwhile. But if I disabled one of them, the code won't crash, but the memory consumption will keep increasing.

```
#include <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <Foundation/NSURL.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s path/to/image\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:argv[1]];
    NSData* content = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    while(true) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSImage* img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:content];
            NSLog(@"Image @ %p: %@\n", img, img);
            CGImageRef cgImg = [img CGImageForProposedRect:nil context:nil hints:nil];
            if (cgImg) {
                size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImg);
                size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImg);
                CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
                CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(0, width, height, 8, 0, colorspace, 1);
                CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
                CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, cgImg);
                CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
                CGContextRelease(ctx);
                CGImageRelease(cgImg);
            }
            [img release];
        }
    }

    [content release];
    [path release];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be autoreleased objected created inside SDK, so try to use (it is always good practice for such cycles with objective-c objects)

```
while(true) {
  @autoreleasepool {
      NSImage* img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:content];
      [img release];
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works, but when I want to do more about the NSImage object, it still has memory leak issues. I have posted the new code in the question.

Comment: @XingweiLin, "bug changed behaviour?" )) - you should not release `path`, `content`, and `cgImg`, because they are autoreleased. I assume [this article](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) will be helpful for you

Comment: auctually, I don't know why in the @autoreleasepool{}, we still need call `[img release]`, won't the `img` object be autoreleased? And the `path`, `content` is outside the @autoreleasepool, why they shouldn't be released.

Comment: @XingweiLin, you need to get acquainted with objective-c memory management rules (see by reference in previous comment official Apple document on that - I'm not going to copy-paste it here).